# Web Scraping Issue: code does not show same output as web browser inspect

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap the public data from the following website: 'https://www.myauto.ge/ka/pr/89476234/iyideba-manqanebi-sedani-bmw-m5-2018-benzini-tbilisi?offerType=superVip'

The problem is that when I run the python script to get the html content, I don't get the full structure, for some reason it's limited.
To be more specific, using webbrowser Inspection for instance, with Google Chrome, I see the full html structre with all its data. Although, when I run simple python script it shows totally different output.

**Python script looks like:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36',}

url = 'https://www.myauto.ge/ka/pr/89476234/iyideba-manqanebi-sedani-bmw-m5-2018-benzini-tbilisi?offerType=superVip'

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

**output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="ka"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><title>ახალი და მეორადი ავტომობილები, მოტოტექნიკა, სპეცტექნიკა | MyAuto</title><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,minimum-scale=1" name="viewport"/><meta content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" http-equiv="Cache-Control"><meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="Pragma"/><meta content="0" http-equiv="Expires"/><link href="/build/apple-touch.png" rel="apple-touch-icon"/><script src="https://port80ge.adocean.pl/files/js/ado.js"></script><script>(function(h,o,t,j,a,r){
            h.hj=h.hj||function(){(h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments)};
            h._hjSettings={hjid:999957,hjsv:6};
            a=o.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            r=o.createElement('script');r.async=1;
            r.src=t+h._hjSettings.hjid+j+h._hjSettings.hjsv;
            a.appendChild(r);
        })(window,document,'https://static.hotjar.com/c/hotjar-','.js?sv=');</script><link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/build/assets/08ce688aafe5f1aeabf1.woff2" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/build/assets/1049b8825e3d853b6926.woff2" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/build/assets/139f7955fb3a247cebfe.woff2" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/build/assets/17645fe55b2c8add5827.woff2" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/build/assets/317a6a75bc8222459cdb.woff2" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/build/assets/5677e60a9ac5ed4e3d06.woff2" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/build/assets/6ba9a206e1d65677d1b7.woff2" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/build/assets/8ac4bc22c200b3fe99bd.woff2" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/build/assets/dff1931edecfd6e1e629.woff2" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/build/assets/e2c4000e8aab66ba90f2.woff2" rel="preload"/><link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/build/assets/e98239eba6a80d2b0707.woff2" rel="preload"/><link href="/build/favicon.ico?ca62a489ea9971770420" rel="icon"/><script defer="defer" src="/build/js/runtime-main-ca62a489ea9971770420.js?ca62a489ea9971770420"></script><script defer="defer" src="/build/js/947-ca62a489ea9971770420.js?ca62a489ea9971770420"></script><script defer="defer" src="/build/js/main-ca62a489ea9971770420.js?ca62a489ea9971770420"></script><link href="/build/css/main-4b914a95ac1d68fce1fa.css?ca62a489ea9971770420" rel="stylesheet"/><meta content="#000000" name="theme-color"/><link href="/build/manifest.13bca767e66c9cca15d78e032bbcba1f.json" rel="manifest"/></meta></head><body><div id="app"></div><script>if(typeof window.ado !== 'undefined') {
        window.ado.config({ mode:'new' })
        window.ado.preview({ enabled: true })
      }</script><script>var _paq = window._paq = window._paq || [];

        _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
        (function () {
          var u = "https://360.tbcconnect.ge/";
          var i = 5;
          _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u + 'service']);
          _paq.push(['setSiteId', i]);
          var d = document, g = d.createElement('script'), s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];g.type = 'text/javascript';g.async = true;g.src = u + 'hoard.js';s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
          var pd = document, pg = pd.createElement('script'), ps = pd.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];pg.type = 'text/javascript';pg.async = true;pg.src = u + 'collector.js?id=' + i;s.parentNode.insertBefore(pg, ps);
        })();</script></body></html>
```

**whereas inspecting the website with Google Chrome I get the different output:**

[inspecting results: full html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RK0Mm.jpg)

how can I get the same html content just like web browser inspect shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see in the browser is loaded from external URL via JavaScript (in Json format). To simulate this request you can do:

```py
import json
import requests

# the ID `89476234` is from your original URL
url = "https://api2.myauto.ge/ka/products/89476234"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0"
}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, inndent=4))

print(data['data']['info']['client_phone'])
```

Prints:

```
995557369785
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

How do I get the url format just like this "https://api2.myauto.ge/ka/products/89476234"

Comment: @James When you open Web Developer Tools in Chrome/Firefox -> Network Tab and then reload the page you will see all URLs the page is loading from. One of those URLS is this API call with the data.